Seleniumを使用したボタンクリック後の動的テーブルデータ取得ができない
個人的な学習で、中小企業庁のデータベースをスクレイピングしようと思い、PythonとSeleniumを使って、動的なWebページからデータを取得するスクレイパーを作成しています。
このサイトでは「カード」形式で企業情報が表示されており、ボタンをクリックすると手数料に関するテーブルデータが動的に読み込まれます。しかし、このボタン操作とテーブルデータの取得に問題が発生しています。
取得したいページ：
https://ma-shienkikan.go.jp/search
ボタンクリック部分のコード
def get_fee_details_optimized(card, fee_type, side):
    try:
        # `fee_type` に応じたボタンの色を設定
        if fee_type == "FA":
            button_color = "bg-yellow-500"
        elif fee_type == "仲介":
            button_color = "bg-green-500"
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid fee_type: {fee_type}")

        # サイド（譲受側または譲渡側）に基づきボタンを検索
        button = card.find_element(
            By.XPATH,
            f".//a[contains(@class, '{button_color}') and contains(text(), '{side}側')]"
        )

        # JavaScriptを使ってボタンをクリック
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

        # テーブルが表示されるのを待つ
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))

        # 更新されたページソースを解析
        updated_html = driver.page_source
        updated_soup = BeautifulSoup(updated_html, "html.parser")
        table = updated_soup.find("table")

        if table:
            return table.prettify()
        else:
            return "No table found"

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving fee details for {fee_type} {side}側: {e}")
        return "N/A"

問題点
ボタンは正しく検出・クリックされているように見えますが、以下の問題があります。

ボタンをクリックしても、対応するテーブルデータが取得できません。
driver.page_source で取得したHTMLに、動的に読み込まれるはずのテーブルが含まれていません。

仮説

ページがテーブルデータを取得するために追加のネットワークリクエストを送信しており、そのレスポンスがSeleniumではキャプチャされていない可能性がある。
ボタンのクリックがブラウザセッションで正しくトリガーされていない可能性がある。

試したこと

ボタン検出とクリックが成功していることを print 文で確認。
ブラウザで手動操作を行い、ボタンをクリックした際にテーブルが正しく表示されることを確認。
遅延や待機 (WebDriverWait) を試して、テーブルが読み込まれる時間を確保。
ブラウザのネットワークタブでリクエストを調査し、関連するAPIコールを確認。

質問

ボタンをクリック後、動的に読み込まれるテーブルデータを確実に取得するにはどうすればよいですか？
もしテーブルデータがAPI経由で取得されている場合、そのリクエストを特定し、直接データを取得する方法を教えてください。

コード全文
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import re

# ChromeDriverのパスを指定
chromedriver_path = "/Users/kazatoy/PLEX/chromedriver"

# オプション設定
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")  # 必要に応じてコメントアウト
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# ChromeDriverサービスの設定
service = Service(chromedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# データ格納用
data = []

# ベースURL
base_url = "https://ma-shienkikan.go.jp/search"

# テーブルデータを整形する関数
def format_table_data(table_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(table_html, "html.parser")
    rows = soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    formatted_rows = []

    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all("td")
        if len(cols) == 2:
            # 範囲データと報酬率を抽出
            amount_range = cols[0].get_text(strip=True)
            rate = cols[1].get_text(strip=True)
            # シンプルな形式で保存
            formatted_rows.append(f"{amount_range} {rate}")
    
    return "\n".join(formatted_rows)


# ボタンをクリックしてテーブルHTMLを取得する関数
#def get_fee_details_optimized(card, fee_type, side):
    try:
        # ボタンのテキストと色に基づいて選択する
        if fee_type == "FA":
            button_color = "bg-yellow-500"  # FA手数料体系のボタン色
        elif fee_type == "仲介":
            button_color = "bg-green-500"  # 仲介手数料体系のボタン色
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid fee_type: {fee_type}")

        # ボタンのサイド（譲渡側/譲受側）に基づいて選択する
        button = card.find_element(
            By.XPATH,
            f".//a[contains(@class, '{button_color}') and contains(text(), '{side}側')]"
        )
        print(button)

    
        # JavaScriptでボタンをクリック
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
        print(f"Clicked Button: {fee_type} {side}側 using JavaScript.")

        # テーブルが表示されるまで待機
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))

        # ページソースを解析
        updated_html = driver.page_source
        updated_soup = BeautifulSoup(updated_html, "html.parser")

        # テーブルデータを取得
        table = updated_soup.find("table")
        if table:
            #return table.prettify()
            return format_table_data(table.prettify())  # 整形されたテーブルデータを返す
        else:
            print(f"No table found for {fee_type} {side}側")
            return "No table found"

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving fee details for {fee_type} {side}側: {e}")
        return 

# 対症療法
def get_fee_details_optimized(card, fee_type, side):
    try:
        # fee_typeに応じたボタンの色を設定
        if fee_type == "FA":
            button_color = "bg-yellow-500"
        elif fee_type == "仲介":
            button_color = "bg-green-500"
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid fee_type: {fee_type}")

        # ボタンを探す
        button = card.find_element(
            By.XPATH,
            f".//a[contains(@class, '{button_color}') and contains(text(), '{side}側')]"
        )
        print(f"Found button for {fee_type} {side}側.")
        
        # ボタンが見つかった場合は "Button Found" を返す
        return "Button Found"

    except Exception as e:
        # ボタンが見つからない場合や例外発生時は "N/A" を返す
        print(f"Error retrieving fee details for {fee_type} {side}側: {e}")
        return "N/A"

# cardsをファイルに保存する関数
def save_cards_to_file(cards, filename="cards.html"):
    try:
        # 各カードのHTMLを取得して結合
        cards_html = "\n\n".join([card.get_attribute('outerHTML') for card in cards])

        # ファイルに保存
        with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(cards_html)
        print(f"Saved cards HTML to {filename}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error saving cards to file: {e}")


    
try:
    for page in range(1, 142):  # ページ範囲を調整
        print(f"Processing page {page}")
        driver.get(f"{base_url}?page={page}")

        # 各カードが表示されるまで待機
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "section-card")))
        cards = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "section-card")

        for card in cards:
            try:
                # カードHTMLを取得してBeautifulSoupで解析
                card_html = card.get_attribute('outerHTML')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(card_html, "html.parser")

                # 企業名を抽出
                company_name = soup.find("h1", class_="text-base sm:text-lg py-4 font-bold bg-main text-white px-4 -mx-4 sm:-mx-8")
                company_name = company_name.find("div", class_="inline-block").get_text(strip=True) if company_name else "N/A"

                # 企業名がN/Aならスキップ
                if company_name == "N/A":
                    print("Skipping card with no company name")
                    continue

                print(f"企業名: {company_name}")

                # 基本情報を取得
                support_type = soup.find("span", text="M&A支援機関の種類")
                support_type = support_type.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if support_type else "N/A"

                if support_type == "N/A":
                    print("Skipping card with no support type")
                    continue

                start_date = soup.find("p", text="M&A支援業務開始時期")
                start_date = start_date.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if start_date else "N/A"

                dedicated_employees = soup.find("p", text="M&A支援業務専従者の従業員数")
                dedicated_employees = dedicated_employees.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if dedicated_employees else "N/A"

                target_area = soup.find("p", text="支援業務提供都道府県")
                target_area = target_area.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if target_area else "N/A"

                corporation_number = soup.find("p", text="法人番号")
                corporation_number = corporation_number.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if corporation_number else "N/A"

                representative_name = soup.find("p", text="代表者氏名")
                representative_name = representative_name.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if representative_name else "N/A"

                address = soup.find("p", text="本店所在地")
                address = address.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if address else "N/A"

                hp = soup.find("p", text="会社HP")
                hp = hp.find_next("a")["href"].strip() if hp else "N/A"

                capital = soup.find("p", text="資本金")
                capital = capital.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if capital else "N/A"

                total_employees = soup.find("p", text="従業員数")
                total_employees = total_employees.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True) if total_employees else "N/A"

                # ボタンごとのテーブルHTMLを取得
                mediator_fee_transferee = get_fee_details_optimized(card, "仲介", "譲受")
                mediator_fee_transferor = get_fee_details_optimized(card, "仲介", "譲渡")
                fa_fee_transferee = get_fee_details_optimized(card, "FA", "譲受")
                fa_fee_transferor = get_fee_details_optimized(card, "FA", "譲渡")

                # データを保存
                data.append([
                    company_name, support_type, start_date, dedicated_employees, target_area,
                    corporation_number, representative_name, address, hp, capital,
                    total_employees, mediator_fee_transferee, mediator_fee_transferor,
                    fa_fee_transferee, fa_fee_transferor
                ])
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing card: {e}")

finally:
    driver.quit()

# データをDataFrameに変換
columns = [
    "企業名", "M&A支援機関の種類", "M&A支援業務開始時期", "M&A支援従事者の従業員数", "対象エリア",
    "法人番号", "代表者名", "所在地", "HP", "資本金", "従業員数",
    "仲介手数料体系｜譲受側", "仲介手数料体系｜譲渡側", "FA手数料体系｜譲受側", "FA手数料体系｜譲渡側"
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# CSVとして保存
output_file = "scraped_data.csv"
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")
print(f"Data saved to {output_file}")


Copilotに訊ねたらAPI(AJAX)の応答を入手するにはログを活用する形になるようですね。こんな記事が参考になると思われます。[Python]Seleniumを使ったネットワークアクティビティの取得方法, Seleniumでajax(xhr)のデータをとる, Selenium Python - Get Network response body
